# Como hacer una consulta recursiva en SQL

Tags: sql

Tengo una consulta, estoy haciendo una consulta en una base de datos en la cual calculo los meses de diferencia entre la fecha de nacimiento y los ultimos 12 meses del año, para lo cual defini las siguientes variables

```
declare fecha_01 date default date_trunc(date_sub(current_date('America/Santiago'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH),MONTH);
declare fecha_02 date default date_trunc(date_sub(current_date('America/Santiago'), INTERVAL 2 MONTH),MONTH);
declare fecha_03 date default date_trunc(date_sub(current_date('America/Santiago'), INTERVAL 3 MONTH),MONTH);
declare fecha_04 date default date_trunc(date_sub(current_date('America/Santiago'), INTERVAL 4 MONTH),MONTH);
declare fecha_05 date default date_trunc(date_sub(current_date('America/Santiago'), INTERVAL 5 MONTH),MONTH);
declare fecha_06 date default date_trunc(date_sub(current_date('America/Santiago'), INTERVAL 6 

declare anomes1 int64 default extract(YEAR FROM fecha_01)*100+extract(MONTH FROM fecha_01);
declare anomes2 int64 default extract(YEAR FROM fecha_02)*100+extract(MONTH FROM fecha_02);
declare anomes3 int64 default extract(YEAR FROM fecha_03)*100+extract(MONTH FROM fecha_03);
declare anomes4 int64 default extract(YEAR FROM fecha_04)*100+extract(MONTH FROM fecha_04);
declare anomes5 int64 default extract(YEAR FROM fecha_05)*100+extract(MONTH FROM fecha_05);
declare anomes6 int64 default extract(YEAR FROM fecha_06)*100+extract(MONTH FROM fecha_06);
```

Originalmente tenía la consulta de forma manual en la que yo fijaba la fecha y esta se restaba cla fecha de nacimiento

```
CASE
    WHEN SEXO = 'F' AND (DATETIME_DIFF('2022-05-01', FECNAC, MONTH))>=708 AND (DATETIME_DIFF('2022-05-01', FECNAC, MONTH))<717 AND ESTAFI = 1 THEN 'FALTA UN AÑO A 3 MESES'
    WHEN SEXO = 'F' AND (DATETIME_DIFF('2022-05-01', FECNAC, MONTH))>=717 AND (DATETIME_DIFF('2022-05-01', FECNAC, MONTH))<720 AND ESTAFI = 1 THEN 'FALTAN 3
```

y ahora quiero automatizar la consulta para que se  vaya actualizando todo, es por eso que tengo las variables de fecha de arriba declaradas de esa forma por que mi idea es hacer la diferencia del siguiente modo

```
select DATE(div(anomes,100),mod(anomes,100),1),fecnac,(DATETIME_DIFF(DATE(div(anomes,100),mod(anomes,100),1), FECNAC, MONTH)) from tabla

where ANOMES>=fecha_xx
```

entonces mi consulta es, hay alguna forma de hacer una consulta generica que se repita de forma recursiva o debo hacerlo a mano para los diversos intervalos de tiempo.

espero se entienda.

Comment: No tengo la respuesta pero si te puedo dar una vision de lo que podrías hacer según lo que comprendo, puedes buscar información de pl/sql ya que estoy seguro que con eso lograrias hacer una especie de cursor dentro de un procedimiento almacenado que te calcule esos atributos de fecha con los ultimos meses y haga la resta a todas las filas de nacimiento que necesites, al ocupar el cursor puedes imprimir el resultado de cada consulta y asi obtienes la lista completa de resultados, disculpa de antemano no poder ayudarte más espero que otra persona logré otorgarte algo de código.

Comment: Lo estás haciendo en un `procedure`?